# An integral of an holomorphic and bounded function with singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $f$ be an holomorphic function on $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ and bounded on open set which contain the origine.

**Question**  Evaluate the integral
$$
\int_{|z|=5} f(z) dz
$$
My proposition : with the prametrization $z(t)=5e^{i t}, \quad 0< t< 2 \pi$
\begin{align*}
\int_{|z|=5} f(z) dz & = \int_0^{2 \pi} f(z(t))z'(t)dt \\
& = \int_0^{2 \pi} f(e^{i t})5 i e^{i t} dt \\
& = 5 i \int_0^{2 \pi} f(e^{i t}) e^{i t} dt \end{align*}
As $f$ is bounded ( $|f(z)| \leq M$), then
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{|z|=5} f(z) dz \right|& \leq \int_0^{2\pi}\left| f(z(t))z'(t)\right|dt \\
& =| 5 i |\int_0^{2 \pi}\left| f(e^{i t})\right| dt  \\
& \leq 5 M \times 2 \pi.
 \end{align*}
I can't conclude of the value of the integral.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: If $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$, then how does it have a singularity?

Comment: Thanks you for your hint. I give the correction.

Comment: Do you believe that that integral can be computed without any information about $f$ other than its domain?

Comment: Since $f$ is bounded on some domain that contains zero, it implies that the singularity at $0$ is removable. Hence, the residue of $f$ at zero is zero. Are you allowed to use the residue theorem now?

Comment: $f$ is bounded on an open set that includes $z=0$

Comment: What dis mean by removable?

Comment: If $f$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of the origin and bounded, then $f$ has a removable singularity at the origin. This result is also known as Riemann theorem. Thus, the integral is 0.

Comment: You can check the theorem on Gamelin's book _Complex Analysis_, page 172.